# Embedding video in email - possible?

Tags: email, video, embedded-control, jplayer

Is it possible to embed video into an email that will allow the viewer to watch the video within the email itself in a consistent and cross platform compatible manner?

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube videos can appear to be embedded when being accessed using GMail's web client](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i7YVs7Ze8U), but no, it's email, there are effectively no content standards.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no method of embedding video in email that guarantees playback in all email clients.**

The best current workaround is to use HTML5 video embedding, suggested in [this blog post](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3529/html5-video-in-email-an-updated-guide-for-2011/) from Campaign Monitor. This allows you to specify a fallback image that prompts users of email clients without HTML5 video support to click through to a web page to see the video in their browser.

Here's the conclusion from their blog post:

> HTML5 remains the best option for embedding video in email. Being able
>   to reliably provide a fallback image is most certainly advantageous in
>   non-Apple email clients - then for Apple users, the option of watching
>   video in the inbox can potentially make for a unique and engaging
>   experience.
>
> Our recommendation remains that you should decide if it's worthwhile
>   to send video email by referring to your email client reports first.
>   If a high percentage of your subscribers are using Apple devices, then
>   it could be a neat move. Other recipients will see the fallback image,
>   which you can use to prompt click-throughs to a version of your video
>   hosted online.

Here's their sample of the code you'd need to include:

```
<video width="600" poster="fallbackimage.png" controls autoplay>
   <source src="http://mydomain.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://mydomain.com/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="http://mydomain.com/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

   <!-- Fallback if HTML5 video is not supported -->
   <a href="http://mydomain.com"><img border="0" src="fallbackimage.png" label="Fallback Image" width="600"></a>
</video>
```

Sample taken from ["HTML5 video in email: An update on client support for 2011"](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3529/html5-video-in-email-an-updated-guide-for-2011/) on the Campaign Monitor blog.